# REST API get lookup additional column

Tags: rest, lookup-column

I am trying to get the data from an additional lookup column with REST API.
I have two lists. The main list is "OIE Alerts" and the second list is Countries.
The main list has the field "Country" which is a lookup column. It is connected with the field LandName in the Countries list. The additional field is "LandCode". How can I retrieve the additional column with $expand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below endpoint:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listtitle')/items?$select=Title,Country/LandName,Country/LandCode&$expand=LandName
```

`LandCode` column type should not be lookup/user/multi text in Countries.

Comment: Thanks Praveen,

LandCode is a single line textfield.
So I don't have to add LandCode in the $expand?

Comment: not required, you have to mention in the Select only